# Sinatra before filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

I'm on Sinatra and i don't understand how to deal with my problem:

I want to "send" to curl a custom message when he try to go on a wrong path.

curl http://localhost:port/blabla 
It's an error 404 but i want to send him thing like 'error try other path'

I tried with this :

```
before'/*' do
  if (params[:splat].to_s =~ /path_i_want/) != 2
    'wrong path'
  end
end
```

or with `raise 404` but it doesn't work.

Could you help me please ?

Regards.

Comment: Why the `!= 2`? What char to you expect to be at index `1` and `0`? Do you want your regexp to match the whole string or just a substring? I am asking because it is faster to compare strings that using a regexp.

Comment: Yes i should use compare instead of regexp. but i doesn't solve my problem. i don't know how to do.

Comment: Did you consider adding `puts params.inspect` to investigate that the splat actually catches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sinatra has a built-in handler for 404, see [Error Handling](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Error%20Handling) page. You could do all your logic in there.

> **Not Found**
>
> When a Sinatra::NotFound exception is raised, or the
> response’s status code is 404, the not_found handler is invoked:

```
not_found do
  'This is nowhere to be found.'
end
```

Comment: Thanks it was this.

Comment: @echo55 If this answer solved your problem, you should accept it by clicking the checkmark to its left. Accepting an answer helps future readers who may be trying to solve similar problems.